# FFmpeg - Using Firequalizer filter based on duration

Tags: audio, ffmpeg, video

I try to use Firequalizer filter as audio equalizer in my video. I want the filter to be applied on the first 30 seconds of each minute in the video and disabled for the next 30 seconds. It will have no effect on the video for the seconds it is disabled. Is there any way to do this?

I set audio equalizer with duration on command line like this but it not work:

```
:enable='lt(mod(t,60),30)'
```

Even if the code works on its own, it doesn't work with the duration:

```
 ffmpeg -y -i original.mp4 -af "firequalizer=gain_entry='entry(0,-23); entry(250,-1100.5); entry(1000,0); entry(4000,0); entry(16000,16)': enable='lt(mod(t,60),3)'" test.mp4
```

Answer (score 1):

Not without making segments.
You'll have to cut it up into segments and apply the filter to the odd segments, then concatenate.

Separate the audio/video, extracting the audio to `.wav`:

```
 ffmpeg -i input_file.mkv -vn output_file.wav && ffmpeg -i input_file.mkv -an -c copy input_file_video.mkv
```

Here's a shell script:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

input_file="$1"

# Create working directory 
mkdir -p temp/segments
cd temp/segments

# Use segment muxer to create 30-second segments
ffmpeg -i ../../"$input_file" -f segment -segment_time 30 -c copy "%02d_segment.wav"

# Apply filtering to odd-numbered segments and copy even-numbered segments
for file in *.wav; do
    index=$(echo "$file" | grep -oE '[0-9]+')
    filtered_file="$file"
    if ((index % 2 == 1)); then
        ffmpeg -i "$file" -af "firequalizer=gain_entry='entry(0,-23); entry(250,-1100.5); entry(1000,0); entry(4000,0); entry(16000,16)'" ../"$filtered_file"
    else
        cp "$file" ../"$filtered_file"
    fi
done

# Navigate back to the parent directory
cd ..

# Create list file for concatenation
ls --quoting-style=shell-always -1v *.wav > tmp.txt
sed 's|^|file |' tmp.txt > list.txt

# Concatenate files
ffmpeg -f concat -safe 0 -i list.txt -c copy ../final_output.wav

# Clean up temporary files
cd ..
rm -rf temp

exit 0
```

Save to: `alternate_filter.sh`
Change mode to executable: `chmod +x alternate_filter.sh`
Usage: `./alternate_filter.sh output_file.wav`

Re-compress the audio:

```
ffmpeg -i final_output.wav final_output.aac
```

Mux the new audio with the video:

```
ffmpeg -i input_file_video.mkv -i final_output.aac -c copy final_mux.mkv
```